# Activating graphical boot after "server" install

Tags: boot, plymouth

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 server on a box and then turned that box into a normal desktop installation with the installation of packages like `ubuntu-desktop`. Everything is working fine except the boot sequences: instead of the normal graphical loading animation I see the output of startup services in the text console before the graphical login manager is launched.

I suppose that the default Ubuntu installation writes somewhere "...and use the graphical boot animation", while the installer of the server version does not.

How can I manually set the boot sequence to avoid the text console and use the boot splash screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/default/grub` in an editor as root. Add the arguments `quiet splash` to the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="some other arguments"
```

so it will look like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="some other arguments quiet splash"
```

Then save, exit and run `sudo update-grub` to include these changes into the bootloader.

Comment: tried this approach in 18.04 but didn't help. "quiet splash" options were present in 'grub' file by default.